# mysql docker how to set whitelist via environment

Tags: mysql, docker

```
  mysql:
image: mysql:mysql80
command: "--innodb_use_native_aio=0"
restart: always
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_USER: t_user
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: t_pwd
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
volumes:
  - $PWD/mysql/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
  - $PWD/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
networks:
  - net-website
container_name: mysql


php:
image: php:php73
restart: always
ports:
  - "9000:9000"
  - "9501:9501"
volumes:
  - $PWD/../:/var/www/html/
links:
  - mysql
depends_on:
  - mysql
networks:
  - net-website
container_name: php
```

I want to know how to set the docker-compose.yml file to make the user `t_user` can only access from another docker container or some IPs that I want to access.

I didn't find out the document about this on mysql's official docker site or google. But I really need this.

By the default, my yml file will create an user:  `'t_user'@'%'`, but I want to create the accounts like :`'t_user'@'in_docker'` and `'t_user'@'ip_A'`  and `'t_user'@'ip_B'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create users from initial file. Create file `users.sql` with all users you need. Example for one:

```
CREATE USER 't_user'@'in_docker' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT USAGE ON `table`.* TO 't_user'@'in_docker' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `table`.* TO 't_user'@'in_docker';
```

Place `users.sql` in `$PWD/mysql` dir and use volume to provide this file as initial data:

```
volumes:
  - $PWD/mysql/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
  - $PWD/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
  - $PWD/mysql/users.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/users.sql
```

[Official MySQL docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) image description says:

> When a container is **started for the first time**, a new database with
> the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
> configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
> extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d